# Java posting to nodeJS returns 404

Tags: java, node.js, express, post

I am trying to post a simple string from my java code to my nodeJS application. I start the server and when i visit it in the browser it shows me the welcome message.

When i run my java code to post to localhost:8080/TEST it returns a 404 code. What am i doing wrong?

express.js code

```
var port = 8080;
const express = require('express'); 
const app = express();


app.get('', (req, res) => {
res.send('Hello express!')
})

app.get('/TEST', (req, res) => {
res.send('response send')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is up on port '+port)
    })
```

Java code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 PostToNodejs pt = new PostToNodejs();
 pt.post("http://localhost:8080/TEST", "Some data in string format");
}


public void post(String uri, String data) throws Exception {
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create(uri))
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(data))
            .build();

    HttpResponse<?> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.discarding());
    System.out.println(response.statusCode());
}
```

Comment: Did you try to make the post request in a http client to make sure it's working?

Comment: Changed my code to use httpclient instead, still returns a 404. any idea?

Comment: @souvik-majumdar answer below seems to be correct. But I was not talking about the HttpClient class, I was talking about, literally, about some software to do http requests like curl, postman or insomnia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t handle the post method in your express app for /TEST. Change the method to post from get.

```
app.post('/TEST', (req, res) => {
res.send('response send')
})
```

Comment: thank you for replying it works now! I assumed that when you POST something with java you have to use a GET on the other (javascript) end.

Comment: Just to be on the same page, the java code is your client where you are trying to consume an API `(url=http://localhost:8080/TEST, method=POST)` The node code is providing that API. So since you are trying to consume an API using the POST method you would need to serve the API over that same method from your server

Comment: ah now it is clear, had some trouble understanding it completely  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are only handling the GET route for "/TEST", to fix the error you need to add a POST route to your express code. You can use this code:

```
app.post('/TEST', (request, response) => {
  response.send("Post route working");
});
```